# array_key_exists in php with NULL Values giving no output

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following query:

```
//product density
$stmt_density = $conn->prepare("SELECT density FROM product_density
WHERE product_id = :productid ");
$stmt_density->execute(array(':productid' => "$pid"));
$density = $stmt_density->fetchAll();
```

If density is not present the value will be "NULL".

```
var_dump($density);
```

gives following output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["density"]=> NULL [0]=> NULL } }
```

I need to check whether the array is having values or not and to provide select options, if array not empty.

Comment: NULL is not your array key it's your array values?

Comment: Sounds like you've confused keys and values.

Comment: `$density` is a 2-dimensional array. The keys of the first dimension are `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. The keys of the second dimension are `density` and `0`. Nothing has a key of `NULL`.

Comment: As others have stated you are checking key the key, when you need to check for the value.  Also you need to check for NULL, not 'NULL' the string.  NULL != 'NULL'

Comment: @CJ Wurtz How can i check whether array is empty ???

Comment: I added an answer to address your edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you expect to get back multiple results from your query could change the answer, especially if you get back say 1 result with a NULL and one without.  But you could do...

```
function validResult($density) {
    foreach($density as $item) {
        if($item["density"] == NULL) return false;
    }
    return true;
 }


 if(validResult($density))
     echo "We have values";
 else
     echo "Array contains null";
```

The function will return false if any result has null, regardless of how many are not null

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function check($array, $key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        if (is_null($array[$key])) {
            echo $key . ' is null';
        } else {
            echo $key . ' is set';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check for null values in an array try

```
function array_key_exists_r($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $v) {
        foreach ($v as $k=>$v1) {
            if(empty($v1) || $v1 ==$needle)
              $result[$k] = $v1;
        }
        if ($result) return $result;
    }
}
$r = array_key_exists_r('NULL', $density);
print_r($r); //Array ( [density] => [0] => )
```

Function will give you all empty or NULL keys as an array